# sqlalchemy yield_per() batch

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to 10000 records at a time using yield_per(). This gives me all the records of the query one by one in a stream, using a cursor of length 10000. Is there a way to get lists (of size 10000) of records instead of getting the one by one?

```
for record in connection.query(my_query).yield_per(10000):
    foo(position)
```

Comment: this should just return generator, maybe you could required_size_array = [x for x in query(my_query).yield_per(10000)] ?